# ToC-title formatting problem

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, starred-version

I am relatively new to Latex and I came across a problem I am not able to fix myself.
From a friend I got a number of commands for formatting my chapter titles, which works quite well, unfortunately it does not work for the toc-title and chapters with an asterisk (`\chapter*{}`).
Can somebody help to solve this problem?

```
    \documentclass{book}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
    \vspace*{1 pt}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
    \bfseries\LARGE\thechapter.\ #1
    \par\nobreak\vspace{20 pt}}}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{abc}
    \section{def}
    \chapter{Results}
    \section{ABC}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: So you want to format chapters having chapter* right?

Answer (score 2):

Redefine `\@makeschapterhead` (note the "s") correspondingly.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{1 pt}%
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
\bfseries\LARGE\thechapter.\ #1
\par\nobreak\vspace{20 pt}}}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{1 pt}%
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
\bfseries\LARGE#1
\par\nobreak\vspace{20 pt}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Abstract}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{abc}
\section{def}
\chapter{Results}
\section{ABC}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« do the job. It will require settings for both numbered and unnumbered chapters.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
{\thechapter.}
{1em}
{\LARGE}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\LARGE}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, the »[blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext)« package is only for creating the dummy document, thus not part of the solution.